# Python replace string (upper or lower case) with another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to replace the word ?Month in a text with the word August.

```
text=text.replace('?Month','August')
```

The issue is that I don't want upper or lower case to matter in ?Month. Regardless if ?Month is upper or lower case (or a mixture) it shall be overwritten with August. See the examples below:

```
E.g: ?Month ->August 
?month -> August
?MONTH -> August
?moNth -> August
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression (via the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
import re

text = re.sub(r'\?month', 'August', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The [`re.IGNORECASE` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.I) tells the regular expression engine to match text case-insensitively:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Demo: ?Month ?month ?MONTH ?moNth'
>>> re.sub(r'\?month', 'August', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Demo: August August August August'
```

Answer (score -1):

For the sport of it, without importing anything:

```
text = text.split(' ')
for i, s in enumerate(text): text[i] = 'August' if s.lower() == 'month' else text[i]

print((' ').join(text))
```

This will replace every occurence of `s` by `August` if `s.lower()` equals `month`

Comment: output is `Demo: ?Month ?month ?MONTH ?moNth`...it only works where month  appears as *month* (is all lowercase), but that's not what the ask was